# Power BI connection issue to Analysis service datasource

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I have installed Power BI report server (Aug 2018) and SSAS on two different servers (On Premises), for some reason I can't install active directory (Kerberos and SPN) on the servers, but I have created same account and same password on the servers, Which I use to login to windows, however when I check data source of dashboard, it is successfully connected to SSAS:

[image]

but when I browse the dashboard, I get the following error:

**"Non-Windows user credentials were supplied for a non-http connection to Analysis Services. The Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services data extension requires Windows Integrated Security unless connecting via http or https."**

Also, I have tried following options for authentication, none of them worked.

```
<AuthenticationTypes>
    <RSWindowsBasic/>
    <RSWindowsNegotiate />  
    <RSWindowsKerberos />  
    <RSWindowsNTLM />   
    <Custom />
</AuthenticationTypes>
```